# Different external links in Sphinx sidebar per rst

Tags: hyperlink, python-sphinx, sidebar, jupyter-notebook

I have a code base, some Sphinx-generated documentation, and a collection of Jupyter notebooks with running examples of the code. What I would like to do is add external links to the notebooks within the sidebar of my Sphinx documentation. Here's the rub: I do not want to see the links in the sidebar on every page, nor do I want to see the same set of links to appear on every page that has them. For example, I do not need any links on the main page, but when I look at the documentation for a specific module, I'd like to have a link in the sidebar for the notebook showing that module's use and functionality. If I go to the documentation page for a different module, I would not want to see the link for the previously mentioned notebook.

Essentially I would like to be able to edit sidebar per rst, and add links to specific external pages. I'd also like to not have to do any crazy switching in a template to display different content based on the page, since my code base is fairly large and the switch to control that would be ugly and a pain to write (if even possible).

Answer (score 0):

You could add the links at the beginning or end of each page in a dedicated [container](http://docutils.sourceforge.net/docs/ref/rst/directives.html#container), set a class attribute and adjust the styles of your Sphinx template, so it renders the div with this class attribute as part of your sidebar.

Here's an rst example:

```
My specific module
=================

lorem ipsum...

.. container:: side-bar-link

   https://www.link1ToMySpecificModule.com

   https://www.link2ToMySpecificModule.com
```

Then, add styles for the class `side-bar-link` to your template's CSS:

```
.side-bar-link {
   ...
}
```

The exact styles depend on your template, but you probably want to specify an absolute position.

Comment: So the container would be manually written into each rst file I wanted it on with whatever content I wanted for that page, and the CSS would be responsible for relegating the container to its proper position in the side bar? Could I do this for generated rst files as well by putting something in a module docstring?

Comment: 1) Yes, the container would be manually written into each .rst file.
2) Yes, the CSS would relegate the container (all container of this class) to its proper position.
3) I'm not an Sphinx autodoc user, but as autodoc fully supporst .rst, putting the corresponding markup into a module docstring should be fine.